# What is the difference between Usage (Hours) and Uptime (Seconds) in OpenStack's web interface Horizon CSV Summary?

Tags: openstack

In OpenStack's web interface Horizon, under Project Overview we can download a CSV Summary.

[image]

[image]

What is the difference between Usage (Hours) and Uptime (Seconds) columns? The former seems to be how long the machine has been running, while the former seems to be affected by the selected period of time. Is that it or is there any other differences?

The [official documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/track_usage.html) doesn't give any explanation

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like usage is the entire time the server has been activated, where as uptime is the time the server has been "on".

Comment: Thanks, is you answer based on experience with OpenStack or on the meaning of the words uptime and usage? I am asking because I agree with you on the meaning (though usage is pretty unclear), but the figures I see in OpenStack's CSV summary seems to differ.

Comment: I am not too sure actually, I haven't used it much myself, but I agree - it's very unclear. If your servers has only been "active" for 15 hours or so, then the description might fit. It could also mean that the CPU, RAM, Disk I/O etc - has been used. So lets say a cloud is online and everything but is not used, just idling - then that probably wouldn't count in for it. Hope I make sense ^^